# using PassThroughManager and InstanceManager from django-model-utils at the same time?

Tags: django, model

I have following manager, and want it to have the functionality of InheritanceManager as well.

Without comprehensive understanding of what PassThroughManager/InheritanceManager works internally, I find hard to "inherit" both functionality.

```
class ThreadManager(PassThroughManager):

    def __init__(self):
        return super(ThreadManager, self).__init__(queryset_cls=mixin_models.DeleteQuerySet)

    def othermethods(self):
        pass

class Thread(DeleteMixin):
    objects = ThreadManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I subclassed InheritanceQueryset and other mixins and passed it to PassThroughManager.